# Postgis ERROR: could not load library "postgis-2.3.so"

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgis, geos

I am relatively new to postgres and postgis, and I am trying to retrieve data from a database based on a column named coordinates and how close those coordinates are from a point (x,y) I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE ST_DWithin(
Geometry(coordinates),
Geometry(ST_MakePoint(5,5)),
800);
```

I get the next error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library
"/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.3.so":
dlopen(/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/lib/postgresql/posgis-2.3.so, 10):
Symbol not found: _GEOSMinimumClearance
Referenced from:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.3.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.3.so
```

I already solved previous problems installing GEOS and then proj, but now I cant solve this one.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you installed a version of PostGIS that needs a later version of GEOS than the one you installed.

Your PostGIS references the GEOS function `GEOSMinimumClearance`, but that doesn't exist in your GEOS library, so the dynamic linker throws an error.

Install a more recent version of GEOS.

Comment: I think I have the most recent version (3.6.1) I got it from here [link] (https://trac.osgeo.org/geos)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I could't find out the cause of my problem, I am thinking it was due to multiple versions of postgre and postgis installed at the same time.

However I was able to find a solution!, I followed this [guide](https://morphocode.com/how-to-install-postgis-on-mac-os-x/).